# JDeveloper Rendreing issue

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm working on JDeveloper 12.1.3
Suddenly it stopped rendering the pages is design mode and the the error as show in the attached image (JSFF page)

It also hangs all of the JDeveloper while typing codes in Source mode, I should END TASK

This is happening in just one project, not all projects on same JDeveloper App

[image]
Any idea
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your assistance.

**- Regarding to Hanging :**
    I removed the .data folder and restart the Jdeveloper again, but without any change.
I disabled the auditing roles for Application development framework ADF, and that works fine.

**Regarding to design rendering:** 
I'm using GIT to handle versioning of the project and ignoring .data
I did a new clone and that works fine also.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to hanging could you have a look at `log->Messages` and tell us what it shows.

you can also try 
- reformatting your `jsff` source.
- clear `.data` and `classes` folders from your application.